# Node.js: How to make modules available to multiple files?

Tags: ruby, node.js, require

In a Ruby program I wrote, I 'required' all the files and modules that I needed at the top of the 'entry point' file. eg:

```
#Sets an absolute path for wherever the program is run from
#this_file = __FILE__
#BASEDIR = File.expand_path(File.join(this_file, '..'))
this_file = __FILE__
this_file_folder_nav = File.join(this_file, '..')
BASEDIR = File.expand_path(this_file_folder_nav)


#Required Gems
require 'ap'
require 'docx'
require 'sanitize'
etc

#Required files
require_relative "lib/commodity/stories.rb"
require_relative 'lib/worldgrowth/worldgrowth.rb'
require_relative "lib/prices/prices.rb"
require_relative 'lib/prices/prices_module.rb'
etc

I can access all the classes defined in the files above. And I can access classes defined in the 'stories.rb' in pirces_module.rb. All the required gems are accessible in all the files
```

Question: Is this good practice? It seems very convenient to me and I'd like to do the same in node.js.

However, I'm finding that I'm having to write `var module = require('someModule')` on all the files that will use that module. If I have an entry point file for a node.js application, is it possible to do something similar to what I did in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you wanted to make the core module 'http' available to your other files. In your entry point file, you can require('http') and attach that object to the `global` object. Also, your entry point file will be requiring the other files you may have. Like so:

```
var http = require('http')
global.http = http;

var other = require('./other')
```

Now, the other file has access to the http module, and you can do something like:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: You should never attach modules to the global object. This destroys test-ability and encapsulation and is therefore strongly inadvisable.

Comment: @BrandonSmith I see... How would you go about trying to solve the issue of making modules available across different files? I think that it may be bad practice to attempt to do what he is attempting to do.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to deal with the inconvenience and add requires everywhere they're needed. A cleaner alternative would be to create a utilities module that exports items you often need. You could then include your utilities with a single requires. Finally, a dependency injector such as Electrolyte makes requiring the same module repeatedly a bit less painful.

Answer (score 2):

you can make one module that will require all other modules, and then require it wherever you need. something like:

```
var Common = {
  util: require('util'),
  fs:   require('fs'),
  path: require('path')
};

module.exports = Common;

// in other modules
var Common = require('./common.js');
```

this example is taken from [this article](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/02/essential-node-js-patterns-and-snippets/)

Comment: Except, this now means you have to refer to everything as `Common.util.method()` instead of just `util.method()` which, in my book is going backwards rather than forward.  I just do a simple `require()` of all modules I need in every file.  It makes the rest of the code simpler.

Comment: this doesn't solve the need to use the module name, it solves the need to require three (or more) modules on each file. like this you require only once

Comment: I'd just rather to extra typing once at the top of the module file to include a module like `var util = require('util');` rather than have to do extra typing every time I use a method from the module like `Common.util.method()` in your scheme.  I just don't think doing what you suggest is a net win.  It saves a few `require()` statements in one place and makes more typing every time you use a method all over your module.  That's my point.  I know you are trying to answer the OP's question, but I don't think one is better off by doing this.

Comment: indeed this is the answer to my question. just not a very good one :p. Surely there is a better way of doing this?? I'm almost tempted to precompile all the files into a single 'build' using Gulp..